# How to move blog from Not WordPress to WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration

I have a **PHP + MySql** website with blog, that have a lot of posts. 
Any ideas how i can move it to my new **WordPress** website?

I would like also retain the meta data such as related articles.

I can export and import blog table straight to **WordPress MySQL database** with blog title and description. 
But what about images and how to be with related articles? Should i manually copy and paste it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to import your old posts into the new one, you have several options, depending on your current application.

### Custom Importer

You could write a custom importer script. To get started you would simply connect to the database of your current application and `query` all the posts to import. Then you would need to bring the `data` into the right format and import it into the new WordPress database.

> This is the way I recommend you if you have thousands of posts and maybe some custom fields and values, which need to get mapped to new fields.
>
> The downside of this approach is obviously the time it takes. Especially when it comes to files, relation tables etc.

### Third-Party Importer

Maybe you are already using a popular blog platform. In this case, you will surely find several importer scripts or plugins.

For example a Wix to WordPress Plugin: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-wix-to-wp-migrator/

> If you have some basic blog posts (no custom fields, etc.) this is definitely the way to go since it saves you a lot of time.

### RSS Importer

If your blog's using `RSS` you can make use of an RSS Importer. The RSS Post Importer plugin fetches an RSS feed and publishes the full article content of each Feed Item as a stand-alone post.

Check out this one: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/

### Manual Import

Sometimes none of the above options works out for you. In this case, you would probably need to import them manually by copy-pasting them into your system.

> Especially when you don't have too many posts this is probably the fastest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The key of passing data to another engine, in this case WordPress, is to match your database with the database of your new blog.  You can search for plugins in the WordPress site; but those plugins are made for specific applications.

You may find an importer for Joomla to WordPress or for Wix to Wordpress, or any other content management.  Make sure you pick the right one.

If you have a custom website; you may need to create your own by mapping the fields in your database to the fields of WordPress.

```
Ex.: **DATABASE1** name -     user_name:    Name of User
     **DATABASE2** name -     name_of_user: Name of User
     **DATABASE1** password - pass:         password of User
     **DATABASE2** password - sec_code:     password of User
```

If you don't know how to do it; let someone with more expertise to do it for you.  You are taking the chance of loosing or corrupting your data by doing it wrong.  Make sure you have a backup before playing with the data.